# What is the proper way to approach parsing this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

## The Scenario:

I have a website from a school that I'm trying to grab information for the schedules that will be available. They have a tool that's available for all classes which is a form of PHP that send post information after selecting your courses here:

https://campus.concordia.ca/psc/pscsprd/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/CU_EXT.CU_CLASS_SEARCH.GBL

For a small sample I would choose:

1. **Term:** Fall 2016
2. **Course Career:** Undergraduate
3. **Select Subject:** CIVI

I'm fairly new to Javascript/jQuery so I'm not sure of what available options I have. The layout of the website is also really hard to navigate...

## The things I tried:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i =0 ; i <elems.length;i++){
console.log(elems[i]);
}
```

My initial attempt was to identify the elements structure and isolate the text, unfortunately it provides way too many things.

I noticed however, the naming conventions the elements patterns followed so then I copy pasted the jQuery library into the console and did:

```
//for the details of the courses
var tempArray =  $('[id^="MTG_"]').map(function() { return this.innerText}).get().join();

//for the name of the courses
$('[id^="SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX2"]').map(function() {return this.title}).get().join();
```

## TL;DR The Problem:

The name of the courses and all the details aren't linked together by a number order relation.
Instead The information is divided into massive tables under the ID:

`$('[id^="ACE_SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX2"]')`
which contains the name of the courses also. Then after a lot of td/tr it has the the details of the course.

Is there a way to use the selector twice in a row to isolate what is needeed?
For example, something like this:

```
//I know this doesn't work but something like this would be nice

$('[id^="ACE_SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX2"]'). $('[id^="MTG_"]').map(function() { return this.innerText}).get().join();
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `find()` method like this:

```
$('[id^="ACE_SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX2"]').find('[id^="MTG_"]').map(function() {
    return this.innerText
}).get().join();
```

This will find 'MTG_' elements which are children of the 'ACE_SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX2' (both direct children and further Down).

Comment: Since the actual information is always to be found in a `<span>` it makes sense to add this to the selector of the `find()`method, since otherwise you will get duplicates. Therefore the improved selector should be: `'span[id^="MTG_"]'`.

Comment: @cars10 Yeah I actually figured it out by looping through individual tables that were important and getting the span children.

On another note would it be possible to use this information? I tried console saving it, but now I have no idea how to use the text/log file for my Javascript variable that I need.

Comment: @JackyMoon: Once you have the desired data in your array (let us assume the variable is called `a`) then you could do `console.log(JSON.stringify(a))` to generate a JSON string in your console window which you can then copy and paste into a js file. JSON is a universal format which can also be used outside JavaScript.